# Change long variable names in data.frame

Tags: r

I got the data.frame `df` below that have long variable names.

The first part of each name is the main category (rock, soil, land use) and the second part that is usually composed of several names is the levels (e.g. for rock, 2 levels are `sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone` and `sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra`).

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  `rock_sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra` `rock_sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone`
                                         <dbl>                                            <dbl>
1                                     0.000000                                        18.774037
2                                    41.968310                                        30.276509
3                                    32.804031                                         0.000000
4                                     8.669436                                         3.092062
5                                    32.937377                                        19.894776
```

I want to shorten the variable names by just using the first letter of each word to be like below. 
I can do that using for example `dplyr::rename`. However, I have 97 variables and I want to do the same for 20 data.frames that have different variable names. I wonder if there is a faster way to that.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% rename("r_sccat"  = 'rock_sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra',
                    "r_smbcl" =  "rock_sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone")

> df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
    r_sccat   r_smbcl
      <dbl>     <dbl>
1  0.000000 18.774037
2 41.968310 30.276509
3 32.804031  0.000000
4  8.669436  3.092062
5 32.937377 19.894776
```

**DATA**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(`rock_sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra` = c(0, 
41.9683095321332, 32.8040311360418, 8.66943642122745, 32.9373770476129
), `rock_sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone` = c(18.7740373237074, 
30.2765089609693, 0, 3.09206176664796, 19.8947759845006)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("rock_sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra", 
"rock_sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit ugly, but `abbreviate` and some regex replacement will get you there:

```
names(df) <- sub("^(.)", "\\1_", abbreviate(gsub("_", " ", names(df))))
df

## A tibble: 5 × 2
#     r_scct   r_smbcl
#      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1  0.000000 18.774037
#2 41.968310 30.276509
#3 32.804031  0.000000
#4  8.669436  3.092062
#5 32.937377 19.894776
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with abbreviate, but the same can be achieved directly with a few regexp substitutions:

```
names( df ) <- gsub( ' ', "", gsub( "([a-z])([a-z]+)", "\\1", names( df ) ) )
```

using magrittr allows for a cleaner syntax:

```
require( magrittr )
names( df ) %<>%
    gsub( "([a-z])([a-z]+)", "\\1", . ) %>%
    gsub( " ", "", . )
```

Comment: That's probably actually cleaner and better suited than my `abbreviate` answer.

Comment: thanks! I guess it comes down to how much you like R's built-in helper functions... I generally find them counterintuitive so I prefer to use primitives if at all possible.

Comment: @gorgonzola
Thanks for your time and help

Comment: @gorgonzola

I will appreciate any suggestion to do the same for levels of a factor not column names.

Comment: You should be able to do the same exact thing using levels( fctor ) instead of names( df ); boht names and levels return an assignable reference in R, so the same procedure should work for both. I'm terribly sorry for not replying to your comment earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a combination of text cleaning functions in Hadley Wickham's *stringr* package and  text mining functions in Ingo Feinerer and Kurt Hornik's *tm* package. I use *dplyr* for the handy pipe operator.

Suppose you have a dataset with a character vector containing your long column names:

lbl.lst$LongNames

```
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# 1. Create a list of filler words you want removed. 
# You can add to the list provided by tm using the following code. 

all_stopwrds<- c("words","you","want","removed",stopwords("en"))

# 2. Create a corpus (dataset with your text labels). 
# Use the tm::tm_map functions to remove filler words, shorten words to their stems, 
# remove hyphens, numbers, and extra spaces).

z <- Corpus(VectorSource(lbl.lst$LongNames)) %>%
     tm_map(removeWords, all_stopwrds) %>%
     tm_map(stemDocument) %>%
     tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
     tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
     tm_map(stripWhitespace) 


# 3. Flatten out the corpus to capitalize the first word in each string. Then
# Choose the first few words (three generally works for me) and 
# concatenate to get your new variables into CamelCase.  

z <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(z, as.data.frame)))  
z[,1] <- str_to_title(z[,1]) 
z$first3 <- word(z[,1], 1,3, sep=" ")
z$ShortName <- str_replace_all(z$first3, " ", "")
```